# What was Northern Ireland electoral law pre-1972?

Tags: political-history, united-kingdom, resource, voting, northern-ireland

I have seen claims that the voting system used in Northern Ireland pre-1972 was discriminatory. In particular, I've seen the claim that voting was allocated per household and not per person; I have also seen the claim that landlords were granted votes per tenant.

I have not been able to find a good source for this. It seems a critical piece of background to the Troubles. Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: What has your previous research shown? [Northern Ireland Civil Rights Association - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Ireland_Civil_Rights_Association#Origins)

Comment: "plural business votes they enjoyed for parliamentary elections.[citation needed]" : I think what I'm looking for is expansion on this bit and a citation.

Comment: Initially the Commons was elected by STV to ensure a Republican voice, however the UUP pushed through a first past the post system to reduce the Republican influence.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Commons_of_Northern_Ireland and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parliament_of_Northern_Ireland.  You'll see lots of "claims", some of which are based on electoral malpractice and some are based on inaccurate folk memories.  Bear in mind that the Nationalist Party had bouts of abstentionism which effectively disenfranchised their supporters.

Comment: **property franchise** would be the initial keyword, since that was quite common at the time (not only in Northern Ireland).

Comment: Could you edit the title to clarify what your question is? What do you want to know?  Are you asking "What was N. Ireland Election law pre-1972?"

Comment: @MCW that's what I understand the question to be - was Northern Irish suffrage pre-1972 not based on one-person-per-vote?

Comment: Please let us know where you have seen these claims. Quoting the claims and providing a link would be useful for anyone trying to answer your question.

Comment: There's a bit more information at https://cain.ulster.ac.uk/issues/politics/election/electoralsystem.htm